# Rename upload file Magento 2

Tags: magento2, image-upload, file-upload

I successfully uploaded the file using this code:

```
public function execute()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    try{
        $target = $this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('mycustomfolder/');        
        /** @var $uploader \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader */
        $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'file']);
        /** Allowed extension types */
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'zip', 'doc']);
        /** rename file name if already exists */
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        /** upload file in folder "mycustomfolder" */
        $result = $uploader->save($target);
        if ($result['file']) {
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('File has been successfully uploaded')); 
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
    }
    return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath(
        '*/*/upload', ['_secure'=>$this->getRequest()->isSecure()]
    );            
}
```

the problem is I need to rename the file name if I found a specific string in that file name, is there a  way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method `$uploader->save($target);` has a second parameter:
string $newFileName

Also you'll find the method `$uploader->getUploadedFileName()` to get the filename.

You can use `strpos()` to find the string in the file name.

I hope it helps you.